# Custom zoom buttons for Leaflet don't work

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would want to use custom zoom buttons outside the map to save space for mobile screens. I tried this but the buttons don't work:

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='zoomIn'>Zoom in</button>
<button type='button' id='zoomOut'>Zoom out</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function zoomIn() {
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
}

function zoomOut() {
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
}

var zoomIn = document.getElementById("zoomIn");
zoomIn.setAttribute("onclick","javascript: zoomIn();");

var zoomOut = document.getElementById("zoomOut");
zoomOut.setAttribute("onclick","javascript: zoomOut();");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one interesting way of attaching an eventhandler. Normally one would use `addEventListener`:

> The EventTarget.addEventListener() method adds the specified EventListener-compatible object to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the EventTarget on which it is called. The event target may be an Element in a document, the Document itself, a Window, or any other object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Example:

```
document.getElementById('zoomIn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
});

document.getElementById('zoomOut').addEventListener('click', function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
});
```

Since you're using Leaflet, the easiest way to attach events to DOM elements is to use `L.DomEvent`:

> Utility functions to work with the DOM events

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#domevent

Also Leaflet has a function for getting DOM elements by ID: `L.DomUtil.get` so you do not need to use `document.getElementById`:

> Returns an element given its DOM id

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#domutil-get

```
L.DomEvent.on(L.DomUtil.get('zoomIn'), 'click', function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
});

L.DomEvent.on(L.DomUtil.get('zoomOut'), 'click', function () {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
});
```